# Is there another way to make a non developable surface developable by using plane-polygons like triangles, squares etc.?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangulation

I know that a non-developable surface (like sphere, ellipsoid, paraboloid, hyperboloid,hyperbolic paraboloid helicoid, catenoid etc.) can't be flattened onto a plane without distortion (like stretching & contraction) & it has zero Gaussian curvature.  Thus it is not possible to truly make a non-developable surface developable.

Therefore a non-developable surface can be approximated by a surface consisting of flat faces as plane polygons like triangles, quadrilaterals or other polygons of as minimum size as possible for best approximation such that there must be no change in the shapes & dimensions of the flat faces when transformed to the desired surface. This makes a non-developable surface as a polyhedron & a polyhedron is developable surface i.e. it can be easily flatted onto a plane without distorting any of its flat faces just by unfolding flat faces at their mating edges. Thus, a non-developable surface can be made develpable.

[image]

One of the best methods of doing so is dividing a curved surface into tiny plane-triangles called [Surface Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_triangulation) as shown in figure below
[image]

My question: Is there any other method to make a non-developable surface developable besides using net of triangles, quadrilaterals or n-polygons?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can develop the finite elements approximation flat, but you have to make many cuts!!

Comment: Does that make distortion when transformed to a curved surface? I am looking for a method in which no distortion occurs when a plane is transformed to a curved surface

Comment: what do you mean by distortion ? if you cut out all the triangles you can lay them flat onto a table. If they come from a cone you can put them side to side "without holes" in between, if they come from a sphere you will have "cracks" in between.

Comment: Distortion meaning if the net of triangles is folded it should completely cover an open surface (paraboloid of revolution) or enclose a closed surface (like sphere) such that the shapes of triangles or elements remain intact. Do you guarantee that when the elements/triangles are folded will they fully cover the curved surface (to made developable)?

Comment: Take example of net of 20 congruent equilateral triangles when we unfold thenm they form a closed surface i.e. Icosahedron with perfect matching at the edges but if we take higher no. of triangles or any scalene triangle in place of isosceles triangle they can never form a closed surface without distortion because their edges will never coincide.

Comment: Seems that you need to better clarify which is the object of your question

Comment: The method which I know is that if triangles, quadrilaterals or other polygons are transformed to approximate to the required surface there must not be any change in shapes and dimensions of elements (triangle, quadrilaterals etc.) Now, I am asking for similar or different method in which a given curved surface is divided into elements (geometric shapes) which can flatted onto a plane without any change in shape & size of the elements (geometric shapes).

Answer (score 3):

Other developable surfaces are cylinders, cones and other less known. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface.

You can approximate your non-developable surface with patches of those.

[image]

Comment: Good +1.  But the methods you gave are applicable only for making a sphere developable. Is there another method to make any arbitrary non-developable surface developable for example can a hyperbolic paraboloid, a bilinear surface or a catenoid etc. can be made developable by these methods?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: no, these are just examples. You get more flexibility as the patches can have some curvature.

Comment: OK, your examples are good. Are these methods in your answer perfectly make a sphere developable or these are the best approximation of a spherical surface? I mean the spherical surface developed by these plane elements is perfectly a sphere or it has some edges?

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: come on, a non-developable surface cannot become developable by magic !

Comment: Alright, I know that. I have already seen these examples for making a sphere developable. But I am looking for some other method which is best approximation to make any arbitrary non-developable surface developable.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: I am not sure you understand what developability is about.

Comment: What's that? Give me brief explanation about what developability is if you have more insight in developability.

Answer (score 1):

In my geometry studies I have found that some shapes can be divided into hyperbolic paraboloids, which in turn are developable in a practical sense, if not in a formal sense.  Consider this ruled torus produced by a trefoil knot (joined to itself with a shift of $4\pi/5$).

[(3,2) torus knot with making ruled surface by self-adjoining lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1APb.gif)

If $F(t)$ is the trefoil knot space curve, then then the torus $G(s,t)$ is defined as $G(s,t)=(1-s)F(t)+s F(t+4\pi/5)$.  The domain is a rectangle with $(s,t)$ in $[0,1] \times [0,2 \pi]$.  Divide the rectangle into strips like

$[0,1]\times[2\pi k/n,2\pi(k+1)/n]$ with $k$ in $0,1...n-1$.

Now each of these strips is easily approximated by a hyperbolic paraboloid containing the four corners of the strips' image.  You can untwist these paraboloids by defining an axis down the middle of each and then mapping the lengths of tangent vectors in $dG$ back into the euclidean plane.  The resultant figures tend to look something like this:

[Hourglass shaped figure as rotation-adjusted projection of paraboloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXYtv.jpg)

I cut them out of ripstop fabric and then affix them to a knot made from carbon fiber rod.  The ripstop doesn't stretch, but it does twist very well back into the shape of the hyperbolic parabolid.   The end model is quite authentic.